# uniqid() not generating unique values within a Foreach loop - PHP

Tags: php, file, foreach, upload, filenames

I have a foreach loop that is processing image uploads. When I add multiple images they are given a filename that consists of a unique id and a time stamp using `$filebase = uniqid() . '_' . time();`

When the images are processed they have the same image name, and I don't understand why the foreach loop isn't giving unique file names?

I have the `$temp` variable assigned to the index of the foreach loop with the following line: `$temp = $_FILES['standard-upload-files']['tmp_name'][$index];` so I don't understand why it doesn't increment a new value?

The images are being moved correctly to the destination folder (albeit with the same name) so I know it isn't an issue with my HTML form, or the initial foreach loop.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-images'])) {

    foreach($_FILES['standard-upload-files']['name'] as $index => $filename ) {

        if($_FILES['standard-upload-files']['error'][$index] === 0 ) {

            $temp = $_FILES['standard-upload-files']['tmp_name'][$index];

            $filebase = uniqid() . '_' . time();

            move_uploaded_file($temp, "images-download/{$filebase}");

        }

    } // main foreach

} // isset($_POST)
```

Comment: What do you get after: echo $temp after you defined it, and unset $temp before closing the foreach loop?

Comment: @Manny When I echo $temp I just get the paths of the temp files for the number of images I've uploaded (i.e. two paths for two images).

Comment: could you share some output please?

Comment: @Manny - what do you mean? If gives the filenames the same names e.g. if I upload two files they both get the same filename `60e3ad5989fbb_1625533785` based on the `$filebase` variable. I haven't included the code for the .jpg extension etc so I can keep the code to the bare minimum in the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, my first guess is using [uniqid](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php). `Uniqid` is generated **based on the current time in microseconds** which could result in the same values. As the documentation mentions, this function does not guarantee the **uniqueness** of the return value.

Since most systems adjust the system clock by NTP or like, system time is changed constantly. Therefore, it is possible that this function does not return a unique ID for the process/thread. Use `more_entropy` to increase the likelihood of uniqueness.

A [not so reliable] solution would be setting the `more_entropy` to true:

```
uniqid('', true)
```

but again, remember this approach is not reliable.

So use another method for generating your unique IDs (`UUID` for example as explained in the comments [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).)

Comment: Thanks Manny that was the issue.